# Compare two lists of strings of varying length for difference based on content, not length

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have two lists, `imported` and `existing`. They can be of the same length, or of different length.

I want to check if there's anything in `imported` that's not in `existing`.

If they're the same length, I'm able to compare them and find a mismatch with the following:

```
if(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(imported.OrderBy(i => i), existing.OrderBy(ex => ex)) == false)
```

If the lists are the same length, the above works as expected. If not, it doesn't as one contains items the other doesn't, which makes sense.

How can I do this for lists of different lengths?

**Scenario A**, should pass, there's nothing in `imported` that's not in `existing`:

Existing: `"One", "Two", "Three"`

Imported: `"One","Two"`

**Scenario B**, should fail, "Two" is in `imported` but it's not in `existing`:

Existing: `"One", "Two", "Three"`

Imported: `"One","Tow"`

I've used `Intersect`, `Except` and `Any` but they will work on Scenario A and not B, or vice versa.

Comment: What about string comparison (case insensitive)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
imported.Except(existing).Any();
```

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad This is **a lot** faster than `Any ` + `Contains`.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad `Except` uses HashSets internally any should have the best performance of the solutions presented here. (at least for larger collections)

Comment: Should I accept first correct "working" answer or go on best performance?

Comment: @MattSull87 Whatever you think is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) could be your tool

```
List<string> imported = new List<string>() {"One", "Two", "Three"};
List<string> existing = new List<string>() {"One", "Two", "Four"};

List<string>missing = imported.Except(existing, 
                      StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
if(missing.Count == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Nothing to import");
else
    Console.WriteLine("There are " + missing.Count + " items to import");
```

Of course, this answer assumes that you have something to do with the resulting difference (if any). Otherwise the asnwers using Any are more direct to you question

Comment: +1 for using `StringComparer`, however the OP doesn't want to fetch the `List` excluded from imported, that's why this answer seems to be lengthy compared with newStackExchangeInstance's answer.

Comment: Yes, it seems lengthy but if you look at the core it is just one line. As I have said, I have assumed that he needs the resulting difference and thus the conversion ToList and the following test code. Any is simpler though if you need only a true/false response

Answer (score 2):

This may helps:

```
imported.Any(i=>!existing.Contains(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (imported.Any(item => !existing.Contains(item)))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about making the two list the same length by filling with null or string.Empty the missing positions?